# How does the iOS simulator os macOS determine if it is offline or not?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, macos-sierra

So, recently I get this error coming up a lot in our builds on Jenkins:

```
[00:28:47]: ▸ testSendingLocalModifications, failed - Failed to log in loginWithUsernamePasswordFailed(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000025fda0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://example.net/oauth2/token, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://staging-api-ec2.enquos.net/oauth2/token, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.})
```

It runs *sometimes* OK. And it works fine when run on the actual handset. So it would appear it is something to do with the Simulator. This is running on latest Sierra.

I am trying to find out exactly *how* it determines the connection is offline. Does it just believe that if it is unable to fetch the URL in question? Or does it not even actually attempt to fetch the URL, due to it thinking it is offline. And if so, how does the simulator itself determine if it is online or offline? The underlying host *has* connectivity as it happily checks the code out from Github to compile and build it. At the moment it seems like a 50/50 chance that the build will succeed or not.

If I VNC to the build server and try Safari on the simulator I can access web pages just fine, so it appears it has connection then.

Answer (score 0):

in short:

```
import SystemConfiguration

func isConnectedToInternet() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }

    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
        return false
    }
    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simulator is a separate user-space sharing the host OS kernel, so it shares the host OS networking stack. Generally if the mac believes it is online so should the Simulator.

Please file a bug and include the output of `sudo sysdiagnose -q` and `xcrun simctl diagnose` if you're on the 8.3 Beta (preferably while the Simulator in question is booted up). That will help us track this down.